# Remove leading zeros from Oracle date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to output the current date in the format:

```
1-1-2015
```

So without the zero's in this example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS today 
FROM dual
```

Output:

```
17-06-2015
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use fm before MM.

Query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-fmMM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual;
```

Output

```
17-6-2015
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216

Add:

To have all leading zero's removed:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'fmDD-MM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual;

1-1-2015
```

To remove leading zero from month number:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-fmMM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual;

01-1-2015
```

fm works as a switch. In this example DD is fine, but MM has the leading zero again.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'fmDD-fmMM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual;

1-01-2015
```

Comment: Looks like it's probably needed at the beginning of the format picture, to achieve 1-1-2015 otherwise you get 01-1-2015

Comment: @David Aldridge that's true. You put it at the beginning of the date format to remove all leading zero's. I will add this info to the answer.

Comment: hey @massie in the example you have given can you please tell me how to deal with the last scenario if I dont want the leading zeros in months as well

Comment: @PragamShrivastava If you don't want leading zeros in months and days you can use the part where I wrote "To have all leading zero's removed:" SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'fmDD-MM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual; --> 1-1-2015

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'fmDD-fmMM-YYYY') AS today FROM dual
```

FM is fill mode, you can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm)

Comment: No, FM is a switch that turns fill mode off or on, so by using it twice you've turned fill mode on for the day number and off for the month number. Just use 'fmDD-MM-YYYY'.